# Javascript extending what is returned from a function?

Tags: javascript, python, overriding

There is this function (updated with more code):

```
openerp.web_calendar = function(instance) {
    var _t = instance.web._t,
        _lt = instance.web._lt,
        QWeb = instance.web.qweb;

    function get_fc_defaultOptions() {
        shortTimeformat = Date.CultureInfo.formatPatterns.shortTime;
        var dateFormat = Date.normalizeFormat(instance.web.strip_raw_chars(_t.database.parameters.date_format));
        return {
            weekNumberTitle: _t("W"),
            allDayText: _t("All day"),
            buttonText : {
                today:    _t("Today"),
                month:    _t("Month"),
                week:     _t("Week"),
                day:      _t("Day")
            },
            monthNames: Date.CultureInfo.monthNames,
            monthNamesShort: Date.CultureInfo.abbreviatedMonthNames,
            dayNames: Date.CultureInfo.dayNames,
            dayNamesShort: Date.CultureInfo.abbreviatedDayNames,
            firstDay: Date.CultureInfo.firstDayOfWeek,
            weekNumbers: true,
            axisFormat : shortTimeformat.replace(/:mm/,'(:mm)'),
            timeFormat : {
               // for agendaWeek and agendaDay               
               agenda: shortTimeformat + '{ - ' + shortTimeformat + '}', // 5:00 - 6:30
                // for all other views
                '': shortTimeformat.replace(/:mm/,'(:mm)'),  // 7pm
            },
            titleFormat: {
                month: 'MMMM yyyy',
                week: dateFormat + "{ '&#8212;'"+ dateFormat,
                day: dateFormat,
            },
            columnFormat: {
                month: 'ddd',
                week: 'ddd ' + dateFormat,
                day: 'dddd ' + dateFormat,
            },
            weekMode : 'liquid',
            aspectRatio: 1.8,
            snapMinutes: 15,
        };
    }
};
```

I want to extend what is returned. To be exact, I need to `month: 'h:mm{ - h:mm}'` in `timeFormat` object.

In Python I could do something like this (if return would be a dictionary):

```
def some_class(object):
    def get_fc_defaultOptions(self):
        ret = super(some_class, self).get_fc_defaultOptions()
        ret['timeFormat']['month'] = 'h:mm{ - h:mm}'
        return ret
```

What is equivalent or similar in JavaScript?

Comment: Should you show the entire code? You could have limited to the code with which your problem can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

You just assign to the properties of the object it returns:

```
var obj = get_fc_defaultOptions();
obj.timeFormat.month = 'h:mm{ - h:mm}';
```

Or if you want to have a function you can call to do that:

```
function some_class() {
    var obj = get_fc_defaultOptions();
    obj.timeFormat.month = 'h:mm{ - h:mm}';
    return obj;
}
```

Usage:

```
var obj = some_class();
console.log(obj.timeFormat.month); // 'h:mm{ - h:mm}'
```

(I wouldn't call it `some_class`, though.)

Answer (score 1):

You want a new class that has get_fc_options?

Well, seeing as get_fc_defaultOptions is a basic function, you'd simply make your class

```
function YourClass() {
    this.get_fc_defaultOptions = function () {
        var ret = get_fc_defaultOptions(); // This calls the global function
        // Your code here
        return ret;
    }
}

var instance = new YourClass();
```

I hope I'm understanding your question correctly, really shouldn't be answering questions after being awake 26 hours straight.

Comment: I'm kind of new to javascript (so don't know if new class is an approach in js), so I gave an example what I would do in python to solve such problem. In python I would simply inherit from class I want to modify (well I gave an example of `object`, so let say that class have that method). And then I would override it safely with super extending what is put in return).

Comment: Yeah, inheriting/extending is a bit annoying in javascript... That's why I suggested my way, adding this new function (class) which calls your original method.